# Can I get the current angle of rotation of my canvas context?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering if there is a way of getting an angle of rotation of my canvas. instead of keep tracking of it with a variable like this:

```
 var angle = 0; // keeps track of the current angle of the ctx
 ctx.rotate( Math.PI / 2 );
 angle+= Math.Pi / 2;
 ...
 ctx.rotate( Math.Pi / 7 );
 angle+= Math.Pi / 7;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern browsers, you can, thanks to the [`ctx.getTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform) method which will return a *DOMMatrix* representing the current transform applied on the context.

From there to extract the rotation, you can get the *arctangent* of the `b1` and `a1` values in the `{a, b, c, d , e, f}` matrix. (`m12`, and `m11` properties map to the same values).

```js
// returns the current rotation in radians, ranged [0, 2π]
function getRotation(ctx) {
  const mat = ctx.getTransform();
  const rad = Math.atan2(mat.b, mat.a);
  if (rad < 0) { // angle is > Math.PI
    return rad + Math.PI * 2;
  }
  return rad;
}

const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

function setAngle() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset the transform matrix
  let angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  console.log(angle, getRotation(ctx));
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = setAngle;
```

```html
<button>set and get rotation</button>
```

You may notice that the set angle and gotten one are not exactly the same (at least in FF), I will put it on the back of rounding issues.

Comment: This method still works, but using ctx.getTransform() instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform

Comment: @MikeBattaglia thanks for the notice, I completely missed your message and saw it only now.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `prototype` of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` to support this.

**TypeScript Code**

This ensures that editors will show the proper code completions for the `context.rotation` property.

```
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D {
   rotation: number;
}

{
   const rotate = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.rotate;
   Object.assign(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, {
      rotate (angle: number) {
         rotate.call(this, angle);
         this.rotation += angle;
      },
      rotation: 0
   });
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

Use this if you don't know what TypeScript is.

```js
{
    const rotate = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.rotate;
    Object.assign(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, {
        rotate (angle) {
            rotate.call(this, angle);
            this.rotation += angle;
        },
        rotation: 0
    });
}
```

**Usage**

Any context created after the above code is executed will have a `rotation` property. For radians, use `context.rotation`. For degrees, use `context.rotation * 180 / Math.PI`.